# How to load all associations for a result set in a single query in Doctrine2

Tags: php, optimization, orm, doctrine-orm

I have some pretty basic entities, containing stories and tags, which I'm trying to load as efficiently as possible.

When I query for stories like this:

```
SELECT a FROM Foo\Article a WHERE a.id IN (1,2,3,4,5)
```

I see see the following SQL queries being run:

```
SELECT f0_.id AS id_0, f0_.title AS title_1 FROM foo_article f0_ WHERE f0_.id IN (1, 2, 3)
SELECT t0.name AS name_1, t0.article_id AS article_id_2 FROM foo_tag t0 WHERE t0.article_id = 1
SELECT t0.name AS name_1, t0.article_id AS article_id_2 FROM foo_tag t0 WHERE t0.article_id = 2
SELECT t0.name AS name_1, t0.article_id AS article_id_2 FROM foo_tag t0 WHERE t0.article_id = 3
```

Where I would like to see this:

```
SELECT f0_.id AS id_0, f0_.title AS title_1 FROM foo_article f0_ WHERE f0_.id IN (1, 2, 3)
SELECT t0.name AS name_1, t0.article_id AS article_id_2 FROM foo_tag t0 WHERE t0.article_id IN (1, 2, 3);
```

Source code looks like this. Abbreviated from the actual code.

```
<?php
namespace Foo;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * Class Tag
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo_tag")
 *
 * @package Foo
 */
class Tag {

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     * @ORM\Id()
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\Foo\Article",cascade={"persist"},fetch="LAZY",inversedBy="tags")
     * @ORM\Id()
     */
    protected $article;
}

/**
 * Class Article
 *
 * @ORM\Entity()
 * @ORM\Table(name="foo_article")
 *
 * @package Foo
 */
class Article {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer", name="id") @ORM\GeneratedValue
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string")
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\Foo\Tag",mappedBy="article",cascade={"persist"},fetch="EAGER")
     */
    protected $tags;

}
```

Comment: What happens if you change `fetch="LAZY"` with `fetch="EAGER"`? That would be my first port of call. I'd also check to see how doctrine generates the queries, because it's likely individual queries are being churned out to improve caching. If all else fails, you can write your own entity manager and have a method with a custom DQL query that does what you want/need it to do

Comment: When I change fetch to EAGER on Tag::$article, the queries for tags will join Article. Resulting in more overhead.

Comment: `JOIN` isn't as evil as you seem to think it is: depending on the storage engine, and other parameters concerning the server setup, a `JOIN` might just be the best way. If you're not using `ndbcluster`, and you've indexed your tables properly (which doctrine should do for you), a `JOIN` query is very likely to be the most efficient way. Look at it like this: PHP/Doctrine has to generate 1 query, instead of 4 (2 at best, if you write your own EM method). The more queries, the more resources are involved on either side (both for DB and PHP)

Comment: That's because the DB has to process (hash, check for execution plan, parse, compile, create exec plan + optimize, store plan, create result set, etc...) each query separately. Honestly, if you're not using a MySQL cluster, a simple join is most likely the best option. [Quick google on a query lifecycle returned this](http://lincolnblog.net/?p=216), I haven't looked at it in detail, but at first glance, it seemed pretty accurate

Comment: I don't think a JOIN Is evil. I love joins. What I don't love is when Doctrine first loads the Article's, and then for every Article loads the associated Tag, where the database result contains all fields from Article joined together with each Tag. That's just too much overhead, and why I have Tag::$article marked as lazy.

Comment: Doctrine _has_ to load the entities separately, simply because you're dealing with a _oneToMany_ relation between article and tag. So there can be 4 rows containing 4 tags and 1 single article

Comment: Indeed. And I'm all in favour of loading Tags seperately from the Article. But why 1 query for tags per Article, and not 1 query for tags for all articles found in the result.

Comment: Not 100% sure, but a couple of reasons why one might opt for 3 queries are: a) Doctrine caches a lot of its results. Caching resultsets of individual queries ensures that the cache is more likely to be reusable (using a single IN (1, 2, 3, 4) means the cache is only reusable if those exact same articles are queried again, other queries with IN(1, 3, 4) would trigger a new query, instead of drawing upon the cache.

Comment: Another reason why doctrine chooses the repeated, simple queries, is that queries like are compiled quicker by MySQL, and an execution plan is far more likely to be cached DB side. (note, this is probably true for MySQL, but DB's like PgSQL in my experience seem to benefit more complex queries..., not sure if DQL is processed differently to better suite the connection in this respect)

Comment: A third reason why I think doctrine behaves the way it does in this case is quite simply because there's a inversed relation: you can query the related entities from either side (tag -> article, article -> tag). looking at it like that, it does make a lot more sense to query entities per specific article (the id field determines the relation). Because each article id results in its own query, there's no need to process the results to work out what tag belongs to what article. That kind of logic might be extremely simple to write, but an ORM is an abstraction layer

Comment: Think about how you'd write this seemingly simple bit of logic in a safe, and highly abstract fashion. You'll soon find yourself in a tangle, using parsed docblocks (reflection), to iterate over resultsets that then tell you what getters/setters you need to call just to determine what tag belongs to what article. That's where any performance gain of running a single query instead of 3 or 4 might be lost, or even turned into a significant drop in performance

Comment: True, separate queries would be more cache friendly. Though one might also say that if the entire relation is cached it shouldn't matter how the related entities have been loaded. I might be tempted to agree with your performance argument, but only up to so very few articles (5, perhaps - guestimate).

Comment: I'll for sure will be doing what I can to produce something that is as safe and abstract as I possibly can. Though at this moment my (not so pretty) solution consists of an overridden EntityRepository::createQueryBuilder, that instantiates an overridden QueryBuilder for the purpose of always selecting a custom Hydrator. Which does nothing more than emit a postHydrateAllData event right after hydrateAllData - so I can do some application specific loading. Resulted in about 60% performance increase so far.

Comment: I think you may have misunderstood my abstraction argument: If you were to create a PR for the doctrine project itself, that was able to generate a single query instead of seperate ones, you'd have to add abstraction to handle all types of relationships (one to many, many to many), how you get the key values, how you hydrate the entities... doctrine whould have to allow for all use-cases, because it's an abstraction layer. Writing this seemingly simple feature will become quite complex, quite quickly

Comment: Absolutely, and I think the performance improvement would be worth it.

Comment: The complexity this brings would have a similar effect on the perfomance improvement, as the scorching desert sun would have on a thin slate of ice: it'd just melt away. That was my point. You'd have to check the parsed annotations, examine the arguments being passed to several methods, the cache and compose the most ideal cachable query/result. That's a complex task requiring a lot of `if`'s, loops and method calls (each adding overhead). Again doctrine is an DBAL, while a single query might be slightly faster on a traditional DB, other NoSQL solutions will get bogged down. There's no win-win

Comment: here, there's only a _possible marginal_ win that will almost certainly be a _loss_ of other types of DB systems that doctrine supports. So it's a _possible-win + certain loss_ vs the status quo. In such cases, the status quo always wins... sorry

Comment: Initial test, with non-portable rather application specific code, shows a performance increase of about 60%. Takes a lot of if/else/loop/method calls to nullify that. Good point though, about NoSQLs - my experience with that is quite limited.

Comment: 60% is indeed quite significant. It could be worth hacking out a more abstract POC and submit that to the doctrine project. As for NoSQL adapters: If you do write a PR, just ignore NoSQL connections (as in pass those calls through to the current flow). They excel in quick read access. It generally is faster to hit NoSQL DB's three times for three distinct records than it is to get all 3 datasets in one go. If you decide to create a PR, or a gist even, share a link here if you want me to take a look at it

Comment: I'm actually surprised how little code it took, so far. Here's a diff against doctrine/orm 2.5.1 (which happened to be the version I had checked out). Would appreciate if you could take a look indeed, before I add tests and submit a pull request: https://gist.github.com/interpotential/5fbd6c7a3293d63e39f2

Comment: You're forgetting a couple of things: OneToMany relations can be inversed (many to one), you'll have to account for those joins. You also need to follow the coding standards (`Array()` will probably mark any PR as non-mergeable right of the bat). There's no lazy batch fetching supported in your PR either, and you don't seem to be working on the DQL component (different adapters generate different queries)

Comment: Thanks! Shall we continue the conversation on the gist? Would probably make a bit more sense ;-)

Comment: Correction, let's continue on github: https://github.com/interpotential/doctrine2/commit/a93d918f68967b0e6fc371b9955b2a2338158a88

Comment: PR created: https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/pull/1569, http://www.doctrine-project.org/jira/browse/DDC-4017

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach I was thinking about myself would be adding something like this to my repository class. But it just doesn't feel quite right just yet. I want something that's more portable to other associations, works every time the Entity is queried, and also works with Paginated queries.

Perhaps something in a postLoad-like event, that covers an entire result set (instead of the per-entity postLoad).

```
$qb = $entityManager->getRepository('Foo\Article')->createQueryBuilder('a')
    ->where('a.id IN (1,2,3)');

$list = $qb->getQuery()->execute();

/** @var Foo\Article[] $indexed */
$indexed = array_reduce($list, function($result, \Foo\Article $article) {
    $result[$article->getId()] = $article;
    return $result;
}, Array());

$tags = $entityManager->getRepository('Foo\Tag')->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->where('t.article IN (:ids)')
    ->setParameter('ids', $indexed)
    ->getQuery()->execute();

array_map(function(\Foo\Tag $tag) use ($indexed) {

    /** @var \Doctrine\ORM\PersistentCollection $collection */
    $collection = $tag->getArticle()->getTags();
    $collection->add($tag);
    $collection->setInitialized(true);

}, $tags);

foreach($indexed as $article) {
    $article->getTags()->takeSnapshot();
    $article->getTags()->setInitialized(true);
}

/** @var Foo\Article $article */
// and now use the Articles and Tags, to make sure that everything is loaded
foreach($list as $article) {
    $tags = $article->getTags();
    print " - ".$article->getTitle()."\n";
    foreach($tags as $tag) {
        print "   - ".$tag."\n";
    }
}
```